# All messages receive a "user level notice"

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

Im trying to parse a message from my network devices which send messages in format similar to

```
<30>Feb 14 11:33:59 wireless: ath0     Sending auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx. Status: The request has been declined due to MAC ACL (52).\n
<190>Feb 14 11:01:29 CCR00 user admin logged out from xx.xx.xx.xx via winbox
<134>2023 Feb 14 11:00:33 ZTE command-log:An alarm 36609 level notification occurred at 11:00:33 02/14/2023 CET sent by MCP GponRm notify: <gpon-onu_1/1/1:1> SubType:1 Pos:1 ONU Uni lan los. restore\n on  \n
```

using this logstash.conf file

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }

    tcp {
        port => 50000
    }
  udp {
        port => 50000
    }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

filter {

      grok {    
        match => { 
        "message" => "^(?:<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>)?%{GREEDYDATA:message_payload}"
       }
     }   
      syslog_pri {    
         }
      mutate {
    remove_field => [ "@version" , "message" ]
     }
}


output {
    stdout {}
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "logstash_internal"
        password => "${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}"
    }
}
```

which results in this output

```
{
  "@timestamp": [
    "2023-02-14T10:38:59.228Z"
  ],
  "data_stream.dataset": [
    "generic"
  ],
  "data_stream.namespace": [
    "default"
  ],
  "data_stream.type": [
    "logs"
  ],
  "event.original": [
    "<14> Feb 14 11:38:59 UBNT BOXSERV[boxs Req]: boxs.c(691) 55381193 %% Error 17 occurred reading thermal sensor 2 data\n\u0000"
  ],
  "host.ip": [
    "10.125.132.10"
  ],
  "log.syslog.facility.code": [
    1
  ],
  "log.syslog.facility.name": [
    "user-level"
  ],
  "log.syslog.severity.code": [
    5
  ],
  "log.syslog.severity.name": [
    "notice"
  ],
  "message_payload": [
    " Feb 14 11:38:59 UBNT[boxs Req]: boxs.c(691) 55381193 %% Error 17 occurred reading thermal sensor 2 data\n\u0000"
  ],
  "syslog_pri": [
    "14"
  ],
  "_id": "UzmBT4YBAZPdbqc4m_IB",
  "_index": ".ds-logs-generic-default-2023.02.04-000001",
  "_score": null
}
```

which is mostly satisfactory, but i would expect the
`log.syslog.facility.name`
and
`log.syslog.severity.name`
fields to be processed by the
`syslog_pri`
filter
with imput of
`<14>`
to result into
`secur/auth` 
and
`Alert`
recpectively,

but i keep getting the default `user-level` `notice` for all my messages, no matter what the  part of the syslog message contains

anyone could advise and maybe fix my .conf syntax, if its wrong?

thank you very much!

i have logstash configured properly to receive logs and send them to elastics, but the grok/syslog_pri doesnt yield expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the syslog_pri filter is setting [log][syslog][facility][code] shows that it has [ECS compatibility enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-syslog_pri.html#plugins-filters-syslog_pri-ecs_compatibility). As a result, if you do not set the syslog_pri_field_name option on the syslog_pri filter, it will [try to parse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-syslog_pri.html#plugins-filters-syslog_pri-syslog_pri_field_name) [log][syslog][priority]. If that field does not exist then it will parse the [default](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-syslog_pri/blob/97791e8037ddf2e36c93388eafdc81db5e88473a/lib/logstash/filters/syslog_pri.rb#L92) value of 13, which is user-level/notice.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answer, i have adjusted the code by the given advice

filter {

```
  grok {    
    match => {          "message" => "^(?:<%{POSINT:syslog_code}>)?%{GREEDYDATA:message_payload}"
   }     }   
  syslog_pri {      syslog_pri_field_name => "syslog_code"    
     }
  mutate {  remove_field => [ "@version" , "message" ]   } }
```

and now it behaves as intended

```
                  "event" => {
        "original" => "<30>Feb 15 18:41:04 dnsmasq-dhcp[960]: DHCPACK(eth0) 10.0.0.165 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx CZ\n"
    },
         "@timestamp" => 2023-02-15T17:41:04.977038615Z,
    "message_payload" => "Feb 15 18:41:04 dnsmasq-dhcp[960]: DHCPACK(eth0) 10.0.0.165 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx CZ\n",
                "log" => {
        "syslog" => {
            "severity" => {
                "code" => 6,
                "name" => "informational"
            },
            "facility" => {
                "code" => 3,
                "name" => "daemon"
            }

}
    },
        "syslog_code" => "30",
               "host" => {
        "ip" => "xx.xx.xx.xx"
    } }
```

i will adjust the message a bit to fit my needs,
but that is out of the scope of this question

**thank you very much!**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).